# Prove that $|b|=p^{k+m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Assume that p is prime, $|G|= p^t$, $b \in G$, $b^{p^k} \neq e$, and $|b^{p^k}|=p^m$. Prove that $|b|=p^{k+m}$.

Proof: I started like this, not sure how to finish it.

Assume that $|G|= p^t$, $b \in G$, $b^{p^k} \neq e$, and $|b^{p^k}|=p^m$.

Then ($b^{p^k})^{p^m} = e = b^{p^k.p^m} = b^{p^{k+m}}$

How do I show that $p^{m+k}$ is smallest.

Does this work?

Assume that $(b^{p^k})^s=e$, then $p^m|s$.
Then $p^kp^m|p^ks$. Then $p^{m+k}|p^ks$. Thus $p^{m+k}$ is the smallest such number that $b^{p^{m+k}}=e$.

Comment: Where are you using that $p$ is prime?

Comment: I don't, I don't know where to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $|b|$ divides $|G|=p^t$. Thus $|b|=p^l$ for some $l$.

Since $b^{p^{m+k}}=e$, and $p^l$ is the smallest such number, you know that $ l \leq m+k$.

Assume by contradiction that $l <  m+k$. Then, since $m+k-l-1 \geq 0$ we have

$$(b^{p^m})^{p^{k-1}}=b^{p^{m+k-1}}=(b^{p^l})^{p^{m+k-l-1}}=e^{p^{m+k-l-1}}=e$$

which contradicts

$$|b^{p^m}|=p^k$$

**The idea of the proof is actually very simple:** Since $|G|=p^t$, for any $c$ we have $s^{p^j}=e \Rightarrow s^{p^{j+u}}=e$ for all $u \geq 0$.

THus

$$b^{p^s}=e \Leftrightarrow s \geq \log_p |b| \,,$$
$$(b^{p^k})^{p^s}=e \Leftrightarrow s \geq \log_p |b^{p^k}| \,.$$